# What is this method called of calculating corrections for calculated values from measured values?

Tags: algorithms, applications

I am dealing with a piece of software which calculates temperatures, and corrects these based on measurements (which may be in error) as follows:-

1. The difference between the corresponding calculated and measured temperatures are found, and arranged in ascending order.
2. From this set of temperature differences, subsets are found for which the difference between the largest and smallest element of the subset is less than or equal to some constant.
3. The average of the elements of the largest subset is used as a correction to the measured values.

Does anyone know what this method is called, and where I might find out more about it?

Comment: This looks like a modified version of a [Winsorized mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winsorized_mean) of the differences.